# How to compute a portfolio PnL and Sharpe?

Tags: portfolio, sharpe-ratio, pnl

I understand this is quite the common question but I haven't been able to understand this concept through the previous posts.

My situation is that each day, I'm interested in buying/selling one financial instrument (always the same). Every day, I have a signal that tells me if I should buy or sell or do nothing. In order to test this signal, I'm trying to backtest the strategy on a 5 years period and I have two questions:

1. How do I compute the PnL? I believe I should specify an initial fortune $V_0$ that I'm willing to invest on day 0. Then, if say my first signal tells me to buy, should I substract the today's price of the instrument $S_0$ to $V_0$ and my PnL today would be $V_0 - S_0$? What about the other days and the total PnL?

What if my first signal tells me to sell? How can I do that when I don't have any positions?

2. My signals are the expected value $\mu_t$ and the risk $\sigma_t$ of the instrument's return on each day $t$. I can from then compute a daily Sharpe ratio $\text{Sharpe}_t = \mu_t/\sigma_t$ . If I want to have a Sharpe ratio of at least $1$ at the end of the 5 years, then I believe I should buy/sell on day $t$ if $|\text{Sharpe}_t| > 1/\sqrt{5\times250}$, is that right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding Q1, at time 0 the price hasn't changed yet, so your holdings would be what you've spent buying stock ($kS_0$, with $k$ the number of shares) plus what you have left over: $V_0 - kS_0$. In any case, your day-0 wealth is your initial capital $V_0$. In terms of PnL, you select a "benchmark" (typically your initial wealth $V_0$) and use $V_t-V_0$ as your PnL (so how much you've made so far). You can also use percentages for this, e.g. $(V_t-V_0)/V_0$ or log-returns, etc.

Answer (score 1):

On any day you should keep track of two things: The cash on hand $V_t$ and the amount of the asset you own $A_t$ ($A$ can be negative if you allow short positions. Or if you want you can restrict $A$ to a range such as $0\le A_t \le U$ for example, or $-1 \le A_t \le 1$ for a simple startegy that is either neutral or long/short 1 unit). You don't allow the cash $V_t$ to go negative (print an error message if this happens).

When you buy the asset, $V$ decreases by the cost of the asset and $A$ increases by 1. When you sell, the opposite: the cash $V$ increases by the price of the asset and $A$ decreases by 1. It does not matter which event come first.

On any day your wealth is $W_t=V_t+P_t*A_t$, where $P$ is the price of the asset. The P&L is $\pi_t=W_t-W_{t-1}$ and the return is $r_t=\frac{W_t-W_{t-1}}{W_{t-1}} $

Comment: Thank you for your detailled answer.
Do you know if my reasoning for the second question is correct?

Comment: I don't know about the 2d question.